# IntelliSense is not working in VS2019 for my XML document to which I have a schema attached

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, visual-studio-2019

I thought if I attach a schema to an XML document, I would get IntelliSense for all the tag and attribute names? But that doesn't seem to be working. I tried adding this to my root tag:

`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../schema1.xsd"`

And I also tried adding my schema to the list of schemas under Properties > Schemas in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not care. I have reported this and found one other report...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2019-does-not-detect-xsd-s/1458785
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/intellisense-ignores-xsd-schema-definitions/554115?viewtype=all

The only way I have found to work around this is to have these xsd schemas actively open in Visual Studio. Keep in mind though, that if you have the xsd schemas open, close and re-open VS, even if those schemas still appear "open" because they are visible in file tabs, you still have to manually go to them or re-open them before you get intellisense back.

This is a clear regression and it's very frustrating that MS would ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

We run in a similar problem, and I like to leave a tip here for others.

The schemas in Visual Studio will be cleared after closing Visual Studio. Adding them permanently, seems not to be a good idea, because the schemas must be placed on the pc in a special folder. So, they can’t be placed in the repo. If you update the schema, every dev must update it on the pc. That doesn’t sound great.

We ended, adding the scheme in the Solution. Note, that the schema must be on the same level as the xml or above. We need it at multiple places, so we added it on the solution level itself.

Further information for VS22
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xml-tools/schema-cache?view=vs-2022